# How to center a column in flet framework python?

Tags: python, flet

I want to center this column in flet in python. I don't want to use `page.vertical_alignment` and `page.horizontal_alignment`. Here is the code

```py
def main(page):
    page.title = 'Example'
    
    about_page = ft.Row([ft.Column([
        ft.Text(value='Written By:', size=40),
        ft.Text(value='sljdfklajl', size=20)
    ], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER, horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER)],
                        alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER, vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER)
    
    page.add(about_page)

ft.app(target=main)
```

Expectation:
The `about_page` content should appear centered vertically *and* horizontally. It appears centerd horizontally, but does not center vertically.

[image: Widgets not centerd]

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that behaviour is that the centering happens within the row, and the row is not filling the entire page.

To let the row fill the entire page, you can use `expand=True`:

[image]

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page):
    page.title = "Example"

    about_page = ft.Row(
        [
            ft.Column(
                [
                    ft.Text(value="Written By:", size=40),
                    ft.Text(value="sljdfklajl", size=20),
                ],
                alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            )
        ],
        expand=True,
        alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
    )

    page.add(about_page)


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: But the concern is that i have to show the hamburger menu button on top left corner. All ui goes away when I have `expand=True`. This happens even when there is nothing except of the one being requested here. What is the reason behind all this?

Comment: I am no flutter expert, but I understand "expand" as "fill rest of available space". By placing two rows on top of each other, and letting the second one expand, the first one should still be displayed normally (without having tested it) - can you provide a minimal example with minimal hamburger menu?